# Do actions executed by .bat files get affected by UNDO/REDO functions

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, undo

I often use `.bat` scripts that delete, copy, paste, rename, or move files. I'm not sure that when I execute one of these `.bat` scripts that I will be able to use the Windows Explorer 'Undo' function (and 'Redo' if something was 'undone').

For example, if I have a `.bat` script that simply deletes a file:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "E:\Testing\branches\blue.jpg"
```

will I then be able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo this action that was executed by the `.bat` script?

Lastly, do all functions get treated the same way (rename, move, delete, copy, paste etc) when an undo/redo is used for commands executed by `.bat` scripts?

Running Window 10 pro 64 bit

Comment: You could just try it out on some dummy files instead of waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not affected. Undo/Redo in Windows Explorer are specifically for operations made through Explorer – they *possibly* might apply to functions that specifically call Explorer shell interfaces, but in nearly all cases (except perhaps file deletion via Recycle Bin) programs completely bypass Explorer when dealing with files and directly use the lower-level interfaces.

Moreover, even within Explorer you cannot undo a *deletion* – you can only undo a *move to Recycle Bin,* but Cmd.exe's `DEL` does not use the Recycle Bin, it literally deletes the file.

Comment: Thank you. This was just the confirmation I was looking for.